# Is it possible to combine @ Functions with sessionAsSigner in XPages SSJS?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a processes that uses the sessionAsSigner to do some things that the signer has access to do, but not the current user does not. This works well enough. example:
var db = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),"somedb.nsf");

But now I am trying to add the use of a @ function into the mix, but there doesn't appear a way to use that sessionAsSigner when calling the @ function. 
Is there a way to do this or will i have to create my own replacement function that uses the session to do the same thing as the @ function?

Comment: I would suggest sticking with SSJS but I truly don't know the answer. Out of curiosity, what @functions do you want to use?

Comment: The code I am adding this to already uses `@DbLookup` and `@DbColumn`.  I could recreate them in SSJS but hate to recreate the wheel when they are working so well currently.

Comment: I am looking at a Pure Java DBLookup and DBColumn [OpenNTF Snippets](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=pure-java-version-of-dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique)  perhaps that can be modified to use the `sessionAsSigner` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the evaluate statement for your @DBLookup, f.e.

```
sessionAsSigner.evaluate('@DbColumn("":"";"":"";"All";1)');
```

Comment: I think that might do it. I will try that out.